# Can Cypress be used to automate native and/or hybrid iOS/Android mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cypress, ios-ui-automation

I have used tools like Robot Framework in the past that use Appium (under the hood) to automate mobile apps. I was wondering if Cypress has a similar feature or functionality that allows the user to automate mobile apps with it?

Answer (score 1):

Cypress can't automate native mobile apps. It *can* be used to test mobile apps built with web app frameworks. My own personal experience is that this is fairly complex, and would probably suggest using a different framework built specifically for mobile apps (or the mobile framework your app is built in.) [From Cypress:](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq#Do-you-support-native-mobile-apps)

> Do you support native mobile apps?
>
> Cypress will never be able to run on a native mobile app, but we can test some functionality of mobile web browsers and test mobile applications that are developed in a browser, such as with [the Ionic framework](https://ionicframework.com/).
>
> Currently you can control the viewport with the cy.viewport() command to test responsive, mobile views in a website or web application. You can also mimic certain behaviors like swiping using [custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands).
>
> You can read about testing mobile applications with Ionic and Cypress [here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/07/08/end-to-end-testing-mobile-apps-with-ionic-and-cypress/) and see how we manage testing the mobile viewport in the [Cypress Real World App](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).

Comment: thanks for your response. Well the problem here is that Id like us to use one unified tool for mobile/web/api (something like a Robot Framework). 
But if Cypress does not do mobile app automation then what would you suggest? go with different tools?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Robot, but from what I know it will accomplish that. That being said, generally, specific tools for specific problems works best. For example, Cypress is, as far as I can tell, lightyears above Robot for web automation. I see the appeal in keeping everything under one tool, but I don't think the automation tooling lends itself to success in this case.

Comment: To expand, I'm not even in favor of keeping iOS and Android automation together. Yes, there are tools that do that, but from my own experience I've found you end up writing a lot of if/else cases to cover the differences in platforms. On teams I've worked on, I've pushed for native tooling (Espresso for Android, XCUITest for iOS) instead of a unified tool (Appium).